# How can I get the matches of grep for specific lines?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

I have a file like this

```
Category="A" Type="B" randomstring Category="A" Type="C" randomstring 
Category="X" Type="Y" randomstring Category="X" Type="Z" randomstring
```

I want grep function to return all values of Type, but only if Category="A".

It should return only the value inside " ", and each value in a new line.

So for that given sample file, results should look like:

```
B
C
```

I was trying something like this:

```
grep -Po 'Category="A".*(?<=Type=")[^"']+ filename
```

The results are:

```
filename:Category="A" Type="B
filename:Category="A" Type="C
```

So I got correct lines returned, but I don't know how to make return only part of this string.

Comment: ...also, note that `grep -o` is not a standardized option (only the options documented in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html are guaranteed to be present across all POSIX-compliant operating systems). It's often more appropriate to write some awk code or otherwise choose a different tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to find a grep-fu that covers everything you are looking for. However, it may be too complex and difficult to maintain.

What about just piping, so the first part filters the lines and the second one outputs the exact match you are looking for?

```
grep 'Category="A"' file | grep  -Po '(?<=Type=").'
```

The expression `grep  -Po '(?<=Type=").'`  returns the single character that occurs within double quotes after `Type=`. If it happens to be something longer, you can use `grep  -Po '(?<=Type=")[^"]+'`, for example.

> is it possible to print only unique values? My file is huge, so right now I am getting results: B B C C B.... It is possible to modify a query to print only unique values, so just B C?

For this you can use `uniq`: it shows unique values. However, since it does it by blocks (its default behaviour is to report or omit repeated lines), you firstly need to join all the results with `sort` so it shows each element just once:

```
grep 'Category="A"' file | grep  -Po '(?<=Type=")[^"]+' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

With **GNU** grep:

```
grep -Po '(?<=Category="A" Type=").*?(?=")' file
```

Output:

```
B
C
```